# controller's view inside a child folder is not rendering on web hosting server PHP

Tags: php, yii, web-hosting

I have a controller name OrderContoller. The controller class reside in Controller folder.It's view "servicetype.php" reside in child folder(order).
The "servicetype" render a page register.php which reside in child folder(pages) of order folder.

The code for rendering the register page written in servicetype page is :

```
$this->partialRender('pages/register',.....);
```

The interesting part is that it was working fine on my local machine using wamp but when i deployed it on Web hosting server "HostaGator".
It displays an error on this  partialRender function line that "pages/register" file does not exist.
when i move this file from pages folder to order folder(parent folder) and change the location .

```
$this->partialRender('register',.....);
```

then it works fine.

Please tell me what is the problem, there are many views where doing partial render from child folders i dont want to change the locations on code,please help me out.

Comment: Did you check if your subfolder has exactly the same case? `Pages` vs. `pages`, see also http://stackoverflow.com/a/15785375/291573 ... and it should read `renderPartial`, but that's just a typo here on SO, I think.

Comment: Yes i did check man every thing I am going mad why the hell it is not working...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure the permissions are correct in the new environment - is it possible that folder is not readable by the web server?

You should also not necessarily be using a /, it's usually better to use the PHP Global Constant `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` if you know you will be on a host you don't control.

Comment: The advice with `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR` is not necessarily true. You don't need that if you always use a forward slash `/`. For any Linux/UNIX based system that's the right directory separator. And windows systems will accept it anyway. See comment [here](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/ref.filesystem.php#73954).

Comment: Yes there is a permission to set on folder using id and password in host machine but I did'nt applied.

Comment: I was using \ instead of /. It is better to use DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,Thanks man :)